# Difference of Classic API and Rest API?

Tags: paypal

I'm starting a new project and it consists of paypal transactions.
No credit cards to be used on the transaction just only paypal to paypal transaction. Any idea on what is the best API to use between the two and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to accept payment from both PayPal account and credit card using classic API. But if your project contains mobile solution, I would recommend rest api since PayPal's mobile SDKs are using rest API.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Classic API. it's more robust and well developed. REST API does not support many variables/parameters that work in Classic API.